# Spring Data JPA: using property in @Query as parameter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have several `application-x.properties` files which are used for different profiles and each file contains a property with a specific value for each profile. I want to use this property in queries to database as a parameter.

Is it possible to add it using SpEL or something else?

For instance `application.properties`:

```
query.parameters.role: ADMIN
```

possible usage:

```java
@Query(value = "select u from User u where u.role = :#{query.parameters.role}")
Set<User> getAllUsers();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might do it by following way:

1.- Find all users by role using [Repository Query Keywords](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords)

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, UUID> {

    Set<User> findByRole(String role);
}
```

2.- Create a method called `getAllUsers` in `UserService` and get `role value` by using [@Value](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html):

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    @Value("${query.parameters.role}")
    private String role;

    public Set<User> getAllUsers() {
        return repository.findByRole(role);
    }
}
```

**Other way to answer** to this question is implement a custom `SpEL` that is supported by `@Query` you can take a look this [SpEL support in Spring Data JPA](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions)

Then you should follow these steps for your case:

1.- Create a `ConfigProperties` class so that you can read and get the `application.properties`.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "query")
public class ConfigProperties {

    private Parameters parameters;

    // standard getters and setters
}

public class Parameters {

    private String role;

    // standard getters and setters
}
```

2.- Implement a custom `EvaluationContextExtensionSupport` and reference to `ConfigProperties`

```
public class PropertyEvaluationContextExtension extends EvaluationContextExtensionSupport {

    private final ConfigProperties configProperties;

    public PropertyEvaluationContextExtension(final ConfigProperties configProperties) {
        this.configProperties= configProperties;
    }
    @Override
    public String getExtensionId() {
        return "properties";
    }

    @Override
    public ConfigProperties getRootObject() {
        return this.configProperties;
    }
}
```

3.- Create a bean in order to be called your custom `PropertyEvaluationContextExtension`

```
@Configuration
public class CustomConfig {

    private final ConfigProperties configProperties;

    public CustomConfig(final ConfigProperties configProperties) {
        this.configProperties= configProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    EvaluationContextExtensionSupport propertyExtension() {
        return new PropertyEvaluationContextExtension(configProperties);
    }
}
```

4.- Call the `query.parameters.role` by following format: `?#{query.parameters.role}`

```
@Query(value = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.role = ?#{query.parameters.role}")
Set<User> getAllUsers();
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew about this solution, but I'm wondering if it possible to set the property directly in repository.

Comment: Ok, so far I know, it is not possible but I will add other way to implement, perhaps you opt to implement  it. @kbo

Comment: Is there any repo with your solution available?

Comment: @EnricoGiurin if you copy and paste what I posted here, so it should work.